# How to trigger or check status of chained map reduce (dbcopy)

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, bigcouch

With standard CouchDB view indexes, I have flexibility and introspection into staleness vs. freshness.  How do I get the analogous functionality for [Cloudant's `dbcopy` feature](http://examples.cloudant.com/sales/_design/sales/index.html)?

### CouchDB view query freshness

- current index on disk, possibly stale: `stale=ok`
- current index on disk, but trigger updating: `stale=update_after`
- up to date index, even if that requires updating the index: leave off stale flag (a.k.a. `stale=false`)

### CouchDB view freshness introspection

I can compare the DB's `update_seq` with the design doc's `update_seq`, which can be obtained with `update_seq=true` in a view query or from `GET /db/_design/foo/_info`.

### BigCouch caveats

This is slightly clouded by BigCouch's DB partitioning and multiple servers.  E.g. `update_seq` is a composite and should be only compared within a tolerance range; `stale=false` might choose a different shard than `stale=ok` which might be more or less up to date; although there isn't a way to get the `update_seq` for all nodes (or for the specific node(s) that would be chosen by `stale=false` queries) it can be cheated by quickly issuing multiple `/db/_design/foo/_info` queries.  It would be nice to have additional shard/partition introspection here, but the above still works for my purposes.

### Cloudant's `dbcopy`

`dbcopy` has roughly the same "eventual consistency" characteristics.  Querying the docs in chained DB is roughly analogous to querying the origin view with `group=true&stale=ok`.  Which is fine, *most of the time*.  But the documentation doesn't give any pointers on the following:

- How can I query the current `dbcopy` state?  E.g. Does the DB consider itself up to date or are view changes waiting their turn in the IOQ?  If it's not up to date, roughly how stale is it?
- How can I trigger or bump up the priority of the `dbcopy` (as in `stale=update_after` or `stale=false`).  E.g. I want something along the lines of `POST /origin_db/_design/foo/_view/bar/_dbcopy` that will forcibly push the reduced results to the `dbcopy` DB immediately (optionally updating the origin view first).
- If the chained DB somehow gets out of sync (e.g. documents are deleted or updated directly in the DB rather than by the `dbcopy` mechanism or the `dbcopy` mechanism misses a few documents), can this be detected?  How can it be corrected?  Is there a `dbcopy` "reset button"?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I query the current dbcopy state? E.g. Does the DB consider itself up to date or are view changes waiting their turn in the IOQ? If it's not up to date, roughly how stale is it?

We are looking into a better method, but at the moment the only way to get the dbcopy's current state is to compare the records in the view to the documents in the target database.

> Is there a dbcopy "reset button"?

You can re-trigger the dbcopy by forcing a rebuild of the source view. This can be done by updating the design doc so that the view signature changes - e.g. adding whitespace or comments to an existing view. This is somewhat inelegant but would result in the dbcopy being re-run.

Comment: Thanks.  I look forward to any future better introspection methods.  Alas, changing the source view is worse than just inelegant; it can also be very slow.  Likewise, comparing the rows in the view to the targer DB rows can also be very slow (although we do have a helper method that does just that).  The main reason we're using dbcopy is because the data set is often too large to slurp down in its entirety. :)